# Xcode 8 Storyboard items not selectable

Tags: swift, layout, storyboard, xcode8

Recently upgraded to Xcode 8, and now items on my storyboard are no longer selectable

[image: layout Issue]

In order to select the reset button, I have to select about a cm above it on the storyboard. If I select inside the orange box and move it around on the screen the image pops into the box while I'm dragging it around, but when I release it it pops back to the same type of offset you see here. (Same for all items on the storyboard)

When I run and build, images appear where the solid orange box shows, not where the image is displayed (even after frames are updated).

Comment: I tried adding a new ViewController and the issue doesn't seem to be persistent with new VC's, only the ones that were imported from my Xcode7 Project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen similar rendering / misplacement issues in interface builder for my own projects. In most cases, closing the storyboard and reopening it or quitting Xcode and then reopening the project fixed the issue.

Comment: I gave that a try. Restart of Xcode and restart of computer. No luck.

Comment: It took Apple 8 months to respond, but apparently this is a known bug when upgrading from xcode 7 to 8. They suggested either restarting the project, or using the old version